# aframe 0.9 - White "gap" in mobile vr mode

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

Since we upgraded from aframe 0.8 to 0.9 we have a weird rendering behaviour when we enter vr mode on mobile device (i.e Samsung Galaxy S8)

[image]

You can see this white space in the middle on both eyes which is simply "not rendered" I guess. The hall is a .obj model with a .mtl provided (yes, I know glTF would be better but unfortunately it is not in our hands).
We tested on all mobile browsers with the same result. On Desktop Version everything works fine.  Can someone verify / explain this?

Comment: Insufficient info. Provide a link to reproduce. Images of expected results vs. what you get will be also useful. I see some textures rendered white but not sure if corresponds the described problem. If it affects only mobile is likely a problem with texture sizes (too large) or format. Provide also browser and devices that your testing on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite embarrassing, but we found the solution.

Our external model designer designed every floor tile as a single object... Now we use a floor where all the tiles are one single object and that seems to work well.